# User input and Yahoo pipes

Tags: php, javascript, yahoo-pipes

I made a Yahoo pipe for my site with user input fields, but I want the visitors of my site to be able to fill those fields without having to go to my pipe.

Is a way to allow users to input search terms on my site and that info sent to my pipe to retrieve it and put it onto my site again? I'm new to all of this.

```
<script src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/pps/listbadge_1.6.js">
{"pipe_id":"3c22af6d3c44c390a1eb02f71931e051","_btype":"list","pipe_params":{"userbandinput":"The national","userselectband":"Unkown mortal orchestra"}}</script>
```

Comment: ... my embedded *java*?

Comment: Would you edit your question to point to your Yahoo pipe, so we can see what it does? At the moment I don't think there's enough information to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Visit your pipe's page, fill the form and run the pipe, and then click on **Get as JSON**. This will give you the raw output of your pipe, and in the URL of the page you can see the parameters you entered in your form and edit as you like.

For example I have this pipe here to get the stats of a stack exchange user:
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=36620fce3fa333c72d7db1467a9ff4dd

I enter a stack exchange user profile, let's say this guy:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Then click on **Run Pipe** then on **Get as JSON**. This takes me to this URL:
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=36620fce3fa333c72d7db1467a9ff4dd&_render=json&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F22656%2Fjon-skeet

...where I can change the `url=` parameter to any other user, and the pipe is correctly executed with the changed parameter.